# What's the release variable for the Artifact Name?

Tags: artifact

In the build Publish Artifact step, there is a Artifact Name. What's the release variable for that? I can't find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one for the artifact name, since you can have multiple artifacts tied to a release definition.

Comment: The problem is I found the zip file is downloaded at this location. ZFJ0_BETALink10.4_DevOps_BETALink.Service.SearchPlus2 is the artifact source alias, and BETALink.Service.SearchPlus is the artifact name, and I need to extract something from the zip file name. $zipdir = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(Release.Artifacts.ZFJ0_BETALink10.4_DevOps_BETALink.Service.SearchPlus2.DefinitionName)\BETALink.Service.SearchPlus"
Write-Host "zipfile directory: "$zipdir